# What is the difference between finish and continue in browser()?

Tags: r, debugging

In the help file for `browser`, there are two options that seem very similar:

`f`

> finish execution of the current loop or function

`c`

> exit the browser and continue execution at the next statement.

What is the difference between them and in what situations is the difference apparent?

Some clues about what may be the difference - I wrote a script called `browse.R` with the following contents:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  browser()
  print(i)
}
```

This is the results of using`c` vs `f`:

```
> source("browse.R")
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> c
[1] 1
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> c
[1] 2
> source("browse.R")
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> f
[1] 1
Browse[2]> f
[1] 2
```

Note that the level of `Browse[n]` changes. This still doesn't highlight any practical difference between them.

I also tried to see if perhaps things would disappear from the browser environment:

```
for (i in 1:2){
  a <- "not modified"
  browser()
  print(a)
}

Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> a <- "modified"
Browse[1]> f
[1] "modified"
Browse[1]> a
[1] "not modified"
Browse[1]> a <- "modified"
Browse[1]> c
[1] "modified"
```

So there's no difference there either.

Comment: The c internals of `c` and `f` are about halfway down here: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/main.c [Ctrl + F for `ParseBrowser(SEXP CExpr, SEXP rho)`], but my c is not stong enough to understand how the code executes differently

Comment: Could it be a bug? The expected `f` behavior is that you finish the current function and then return to the browser (not exit). This difference is also there when you look at the source code (see comment above). When typing `c`, the result is `SET_RDEBUG(rho, 0);` where rho is a pointer to the function from which the browser is called. However, when you look at the `f` part it sets the debug status to true: `SET_RDEBUG(rho, 1);` but only after exiting the function (pointer gone) so it should set the debug status of rho one level higher on the stack trace. Just an idea, not sure if correct.

Comment: @takje In this case, there would be no browser higher up, would there? It would break out and start again.

Comment: The only difference that I can come up with is that ´f´ executes the code in browser mode until the end of the loop/function and then switches to normal execution. ´c´ in turn immediately exits the browser mode and then executes the rest of the lines. As far as I could find there are no practical differences other than the small one that you already found. That is, as soon as an already open browser encounters a new browser he destroys the old browser and creates a new one indicated by the increased level. ´test<-function(){browser();browser();browser()}´ followed by c,c,c or f,f,f shows this.

Answer (score 9):

There is a small difference.

- `c` immediately exits the browser (and debug mode) and after that executes the rest of the code in the normal way.
- `f` on the contrary stays in the browser (and debug mode) while executing the rest of the function/loop. After the function/loop is finished, he also returns to the normal execution mode.

Source: [R-source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/main.c#L1202-L1216) (line 1105-1117) and [R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/browser.html)

This has a few implications:

- `c` closes the browser. This means that a new browser call is called from a function. Therefore you will see the line: `Called from: function()`. `f` on the other hand will not close the browser and therefore you will not see this line. The source code for this behavior is here: [https://github.com/wch/r-source/...](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e5b21d0397c607883ff25cca379687b86933d730/src/main/main.c#L1202-L1216).
- Because `f` stays in the browser, `f` also keeps track of the contextlevel:

> The browser prompt is of the form Browse[n]>: here var{n} indicates the ‘browser level’. The browser can be called when browsing (and often is when debug is in use), and each recursive call increases the number. (The actual number is the number of ‘contexts’ on the context stack: this is usually 2 for the outer level of browsing and 1 when examining dumps in debugger)

These differences can be tested with the code:

```
> test <- function(){
      browser()
      browser()
  }

> test()
Called from: test()
Browse[1]> c
Called from: test()
Browse[1]> c

> test()
Called from: test()
Browse[1]> f
Browse[2]> f
```

As far as I see it, there is no practical difference between the two, unless there lies a practical purpose in the context stack. The debugging mode has no added value. The debug flag only opens the browser when you enter the function but since you are already inside the function, it will not trigger another effect.

Comment: It's a pity that there's no difference between them, but I guess things are what they are.

Answer (score 3):

## Difference Between Browser and Continue

At least for me, I feel the answer can be mapped out as a table, however, let's first frame up the usage of browser(), for those who may not yet have encountered it.

The `browser` function is the basis for the majority of R debugging techniques. Essentially, a call to `browser` halts execution and starts a special interactive session where you can inspect the current state of the computations and step through the code one command at a time.

Once in the browser, you can execute any R command. For example, one might view the local environment by using ls(); or choose to set new variables, or change the values assigned to variables simply by using the standard methods for assigning values to variables. The browser also understands a small set of
commands speciﬁc to it. Which leads us to a discussion on **Finish** and **continue**...

The subtlety in relation to **Finish** and **continue** is that:

- **Finish**,  or **f**: finishes execution of the current loop or function.
- **Continue**, **c**: leaves interactive debugging and continues regular
  execution of the function. This is useful if you’ve fixed the bad
  state and want to check that the function proceeds correctly.

essentially, we talking about a subtlety in mode.

[image]

## Browser / Recover Overview

At least for me, you have to view this in the context of debugging a program written in R. Specifically, how you might apply **Finish** and **continue**. I am sure many understand this, but I include for completeness as I personally really didn't for a long time.

> - `browser` allows you to look at the objects in the function in which the browser call is placed.
> - `recover` allows you to look at those objects as well as the objects in the caller of that function and all other active functions.

Liberal use of `browser`, `recover`, `cat` and `print` while you are writing functions allows your expectations and R's expectations to converge.

A very handy way of doing this is with trace. For example, if browsing at
the end of the myFun function is convenient, then you can do:

> `trace(myFun, exit=quote(browser()))`

You can customize the tracing with a command like:

> `trace(myFun, edit=TRUE)`

If you run into an error, then debugging is the appropriate action. There are at
least two approaches to debugging. The first approach is to look at the state of
play at the point where the error occurs. Prepare for this by setting the error
option. The two most likely choices are:

> `options(error=recover)`

or

> `options(error=dump.frames)`

The difference is that with `recover` you are automatically thrown into debug
mode, but with `dump.frames` you start debugging by executing:

> `debugger()`

In either case you are presented with a selection of the frames (environments)
of active functions to inspect.

You can force R to treat warnings as errors with the command:

> `options(warn=2)`

If you want to set the error option in your `.First` function, then you need a
trick since not everything is in place at the time that `.First` is executed:

> `options(error=expression(recover()))`

or

> `options(error=expression(dump.frames()))`

The second idea for debugging is to step through a function as it executes. If
you want to step through function myfun, then do:

> `debug(myfun)`

and then execute a statement involving myfun. When you are done debugging,
do:

> `undebug(myfun)`

A more sophisticated version of this sort of debugging may be found in the
debug package.

**References:**

- R Inferno

  - http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf (Great Reference)
  - Circle 8 - Believing It Does as Intended (Page 45).
  - Author: Patrick Burns
- R Programming for Bioinformatics

  - Author: Robert Gentleman

Comment: This is a really great overview on debugging, but I don't think it answers my specific question

Comment: @sebastian-c - thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer to (hopefully) address your specific question. I have to admit that I rather like takje's answer (upvoted). I was going to leave out but I felt it might be useful to provide a broader context for the use of finish and continue. Hopefully, useful. Take care.

Comment: Your edit is much more specific and still a great overview of debugging, and does talk about c and f, but unfortunately doesn't describe a situation where the difference is apparent.

Comment: Just to be clear here. You are looking for a specific example of difference with an example?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that there would be some practical way to use the difference between them, but it doesn't seem so - as stated in @takje's answer. I awarded the bounty to that one.

Comment: No worries on bounty, let me noodle on an example. Consider, the scenario where you debug, change a variable value (example you realize you are off by one in loop state) and continue to debug after fixing the variable state... You also may have found your answer. I need to go look at the implementation code. Interesting issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `finish` as a `break` in other languages. What happens is that you no longer care about the other items in the iteration because of a certain condition such as finding a specific item or an item that would cause an error.

`continue`, on the other hand, will stop at the current line of the loop, ignore the rest of the code block, and continue to the next item in the iteration. You would use this option if you intend to go through every item in the iteration and just ignore the items that satisfy the condition to skip over.

Comment: That is what the description sounds like, but it doesn't seem to execute that way. Do you have an example where the two behave differently?

Comment: Maybe you can give me a snippet of your code and i'll explain the results

Comment: Consider `for (i in 1:2){browser();print(i)}`. Both `c` and `f` result in both being printed.